# Battery voltage regulation

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-operated

I am designing a simple device that incorporates an LCD display that requires a 3V operating voltage, but I can only use a single 1.5V battery in my design.

How can battery voltage be regulated without significant loss of efficiency? I need this to stay as compact as possible and have very little experience with this.

Comment: It's probably worth adding the current you need as that can alter the solutions a bit.

Comment: According to the data sheet, the current consumption is about 1 uA per square centimeter, so extremely low in this case, as it is a very small display.

Comment: Can you add a link to your display's data sheet?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of boost regulators on the market designed to allow circuit operation from a single ~1.5V battery cell. [This](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv61224.pdf) is one example.

Comment: The regulator I noted works down to 0.7V input which will most of the usable life of an Alkaline 1.5V battery.

Comment: Misread the datasheet: I thought that it was adjustable output. Sorry.

Comment: Excellent device, and a perfect match for the requirement. +1.

Comment: Note that the stepup consumes power (probably more than the whole display). Consider switching off the stepup regulator if you don't need to run the display.